# Running Airflow task from the command line does not work

Tags: command-line, airflow

I am trying to follow the tutorial here for running Airflow tasks from the command line.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/local.html

The command I am using is similar to the one in the tutorial but I just use today's date.

```
airflow tasks run example_bash_operator runme_0 2022-06-15
```

But I always get the error:

airflow.exceptions.DagRunNotFound: DagRun for example_bash_operator with run_id or execution_date of '2022-06-15' not found

The task runs fine from the web GUI when I hit play, but I can't seem to find any argument for run_id or execution_date that will actually work.

I get a similar error when trying to trigger the DAG:

```
airflow dags trigger example_bash_operator
```

airflow.exceptions.DagNotFound: Dag id example_bash_operator not found in DagModel

This is using Airflow standalone on Linux with version 2.3.2.

Comment: what is the name of the dag_id when you see the log in the ui ?